# How to center a Google Map to a latitude and longitude location?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Consider the following code:

```
$('.stores').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('latitude'));  // -1754.26265626
    console.log($(this).data('longitude')); // 65.262518
    console.log(themap); // Properly a Google Map instance.

    themap.setCenter(new LatLng($(this).data('latitude'), $(this).data('longitude')));
});
```

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng), I can use the `setCenter` method and easily center the map, but I don't understand the notation the docs are using.

See:

```
LatLng(lat:number, lng:number, noWrap?:boolean)
```

How exactly do I use this?

I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: LatLng is not defined
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use

```
themap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng($(this).data('latitude'), $(this).data('longitude')));
```

All Google Maps javascript classes are referenced with the `google.maps.ClassName()` notation

Comment: Of course! It makes sense, because in the global scope there **is no** LatLng object. D'oh!