# JS drop down menu

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

[image]

What is the fastest way to do this drop down menu ("choose city", result - centered Google maps of that city)?

I would really need to breeze through some forums and examples, but the problem is, I have a tight deadline today.

I have not got much experience with js/css. Do I need to get bootstrap theme and style this drop down menu, etc, or can I create it with my own js/css?

Thanks!

(Again, sorry for the question without much researching, this is an exception, and not a rule for me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SO question provides a solution for centering a google map at an arbitrary latitude and longitude

[How to center a Google Map to a latitude and longitude location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942897/how-to-center-a-google-map-to-a-latitude-and-longitude-location)

For each city in your list you will want to find out the latitude and longitude and either store them in a JavaScript object or even in the DOM with their respective options.

```
<select>
     <option data-lat="<latitude>" data-long="<longitude>">Location 1</option>
     <option data-lat="<latitude>" data-long="<longitude>">Location 2</option>
     <option data-lat="<latitude>" data-long="<longitude>">Location 3</option>
</select>
```

Then add an event handler to the select box that watched for change, get the value currently selected value from the select box, get the latitude and longitude for that city, however you choose to store it and plug those values into the snippet from the reference SO question

```js
var locationSelectorHandler = function(e){
    var location = this.value;
    var lat = this.dataset.lat;
    var long = this.dataset.long;
    // From SO Question        
    document.getElementById("<map-id>").setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long)); 
};

locationSelector.addEventListener("change", locationSelectorHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use HTML's `select` and `option` tags for this.

And then create some css styles like so.

```css
select, option {
    width: 200px;
    color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option selected>Vilnius</option>
    <option>Kaunus</option>
    <option>Klaipeda</option>
    <option>Siauliali</option>
    <option>Panavezyz</option>
</select>
```